# OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications: two or three parameters? (Or: Can some Google engineers possibly not count up to three? :)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-client

I'm trying to obtain an Google OAuth 2.0 access token for a service account but receive an `invalid_grant` [error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=invalid_grant) instead. I've checked my various artifacts (private key, etc.) and clock timings but have not been able to resolve this so far.

There is one possibly related item that seems odd: Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) says

> *Three* parameters are required in the HTTPs POST, and these are shown
>   below

This is followed by a table with *two* rows that specifies *two* parameters (`grant_type` and `assertion`). Could it be that a third is also needed (I've seen examples that also use `assertion_type` in some fashion)? Could it be that (some) Google engineers (or perhaps yours truly) cannot count up to three? :)

In summary: What are the appropriate parameters? It seems unclear from Google's current documentation.

**UPDATE:** Here is some further information: I can't use the Google API Client Library, because my application requires a language other than those currently not supported by Google. Therefore I have to implement the logic for creating and signing JWTs, etc., as is normally discouraged. I have confirmed that my service account artifacts are in order: I can use them with the Google APIs Client Library for Java to access the same calendar (from another than my target platform, i.e.). In particular, my "client_id" is of the form "...@developer.gserviceaccount.com" and my key is a 128-bit RSA private key, both as obtained from the [Google APIs Dashboard](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now been able to confirm that it's two parameters, not three. Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) seems to be correct insofar as it names those two parameters (`grant_type` and `assertion`) but wrong insofar as it refers to them as *three* parameters.

Evidence for two parameters comes from a current [Internet-Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-bearer-04#section-2.1) (*JSON Web Token (JWT) Bearer Token Profiles for OAuth 2.0*), which defines an extension grant type under [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.5) (*The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework*).

Evidence also consists of having tried a verbatim access token obtained by the Google APIs client library (and revealed by logging) inside my (non-Java) implementation: use of this access token has made the `invalid_grant` error go away.

(There now evidently a problem about forming a SHA256withRSA signature left in my code, but that's another issue ...)